# Remove last character from string. Swift language

Tags: string, character, swift

How can I remove last character from String variable using Swift? Can't find it in documentation.

Here is full example:

```
var expression = "45+22"
expression = expression.substringToIndex(countElements(expression) - 1)
```

Comment: 2017, MODERN ANSWER: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39610807/294884

Answer (score 647, accepted):

**Swift 4.0 (also Swift 5.0)**

```
var str = "Hello, World"                           // "Hello, World"
str.dropLast()                                     // "Hello, Worl" (non-modifying)
str                                                // "Hello, World"
String(str.dropLast())                             // "Hello, Worl"

str.remove(at: str.index(before: str.endIndex))    // "d"
str                                                // "Hello, Worl" (modifying)
```

**Swift 3.0**

The APIs have gotten a bit more *swifty*, and as a result the Foundation extension has changed a bit:

```
var name: String = "Dolphin"
var truncated = name.substring(to: name.index(before: name.endIndex))
print(name)      // "Dolphin"
print(truncated) // "Dolphi"
```

Or the in-place version:

```
var name: String = "Dolphin"
name.remove(at: name.index(before: name.endIndex))
print(name)      // "Dolphi"
```

*Thanks Zmey, Rob Allen!*

**Swift 2.0+ Way**

There are a few ways to accomplish this:

Via the Foundation extension, despite not being part of the Swift library:

```
var name: String = "Dolphin"
var truncated = name.substringToIndex(name.endIndex.predecessor())
print(name)      // "Dolphin"
print(truncated) // "Dolphi"
```

Using the `removeRange()` method (which *alters* the `name`):

```
var name: String = "Dolphin"    
name.removeAtIndex(name.endIndex.predecessor())
print(name) // "Dolphi"
```

Using the `dropLast()` function:

```
var name: String = "Dolphin"
var truncated = String(name.characters.dropLast())
print(name)      // "Dolphin"
print(truncated) // "Dolphi"
```

**Old String.Index (Xcode 6 Beta 4 +) Way**

Since `String` types in Swift aim to provide excellent UTF-8 support, you can no longer access character indexes/ranges/substrings using `Int` types. Instead, you use `String.Index`:

```
let name: String = "Dolphin"
let stringLength = count(name) // Since swift1.2 `countElements` became `count`
let substringIndex = stringLength - 1
name.substringToIndex(advance(name.startIndex, substringIndex)) // "Dolphi"
```

Alternatively (for a more practical, but less educational example) you can use `endIndex`:

```
let name: String = "Dolphin"
name.substringToIndex(name.endIndex.predecessor()) // "Dolphi"
```

*Note:* I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24056932/88111) to be a great starting point for understanding `String.Index`

**Old (pre-Beta 4) Way**

You can simply use the `substringToIndex()` function, providing it one less than the length of the `String`:

```
let name: String = "Dolphin"
name.substringToIndex(countElements(name) - 1) // "Dolphi"
```

Comment: On Xcode 6 beta 6 :'String' doesn't have a member named `substringToIndex`

Comment: @Carpsen90 There is no beta 6. (As of this writing.) And in the most recent beta (beta 4), the `String` type definitely has a `substringToIndex()` method. Can you clarify?

Comment: I am sorry I meant beta 4.. and it is definitely not working for me.. I had to cast the string to NSString to have access to more functions

Comment: @Carpsen90 Can you maybe ask as a separate question?

Comment: Hey, heads up, make sure it's `substringToIndex` not `substringFromIndex`. It doesn't make you feel intelligent mistaking this, let me tell you.

Comment: I just renamed `countElements` to `count` in the Beta4+ way part of the answer. (Swift1.2)

Comment: This is true, as of July 21st, Xcode 7 Beta 4 says 'String' doesn't have a member named `substringToIndex`. Also, as of Xcode 7, string no longer has a `.count` property, it is now only applied to characters: `string.characters.count`

Comment: looks like advance doesn't work anymore either in Xcode 7 beta 6, do you know of a work around?

Comment: Swift 3: `var truncated = name.substring(to: name.index(before: name.endIndex))`

Comment: Swift 3 in place: `name.remove(at: name.index(before: name.endIndex))`

Comment: Your answer is the history of Swift evolution.

Comment: Note that in Swift 4 strings are back to being collections, and the `.substring(to:)` method is deprecated. The options listed under **Swift 2.0+** worked for me in Swift 4.

Comment: That's not working in Swift 4, Xcode 9.  So I did this `placeStr.removeLast(1)` which means remove the last character from the string and returns `Void`, and it did well.

Comment: var truncated = name.substring(to: name.index(before: name.endIndex))
This worked for me in Swift 3 Thanks @CraigOtis

Answer (score 90):

The global `dropLast()` function works on sequences and therefore on Strings:

```
var expression  = "45+22"
expression = dropLast(expression)  // "45+2"

// in Swift 2.0 (according to cromanelli's comment below)
expression = String(expression.characters.dropLast())
```

Comment: In Swift 2.0 the `characters` property on a String outputs a sequence, therefore now you have to use:


`expression = expression.characters.dropLast()`

Comment: In Swift 2.0 for have to properly cast the result `expression = String(expression.characters.dropLast())` if you want it back as a String

Answer (score 74):

Swift 4:

```
let choppedString = String(theString.dropLast())
```

In Swift 2, do this:

```
let choppedString = String(theString.characters.dropLast())
```

I recommend [this](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-06-why-is-swifts-string-api-so-hard.html) link to get an understanding of Swift strings.

Comment: Could be just `let choppedString = theString.dropLast().description`.

Answer (score 30):

## Swift 4/5

```
var str = "bla"
str.removeLast() // returns "a"; str is now "bl"
```

Answer (score 8):

This is a String **Extension Form:**

```
extension String {

    func removeCharsFromEnd(count_:Int) -> String {
        let stringLength = count(self)

        let substringIndex = (stringLength < count_) ? 0 : stringLength - count_

        return self.substringToIndex(advance(self.startIndex, substringIndex))
    }
}
```

for versions of Swift earlier than 1.2:

```
...
let stringLength = countElements(self)
...
```

---

*Usage:*

```
var str_1 = "Maxim"
println("output: \(str_1.removeCharsFromEnd(1))") // "Maxi"
println("output: \(str_1.removeCharsFromEnd(3))") // "Ma"
println("output: \(str_1.removeCharsFromEnd(8))") // ""
```

---

*Reference:*

> Extensions add new functionality to an existing class, structure, or enumeration type. This includes the ability to extend types for which you do not have access to the original source code (known as retroactive modeling). Extensions are similar to categories in Objective-C. (Unlike Objective-C categories, Swift extensions do not have names.)

See [DOCS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-XID_229)

Comment: Hi, have you test emojis?

Comment: @ZuYuan what is emojis?

Comment: Cannot find 'advance' in scope

Answer (score 6):

Use the function `removeAtIndex(i: String.Index) -> Character`:

```
var s = "abc"    
s.removeAtIndex(s.endIndex.predecessor())  // "ab"
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4**

```
var welcome = "Hello World!"
welcome = String(welcome[..<welcome.index(before:welcome.endIndex)])
```

or

```
welcome.remove(at: welcome.index(before: welcome.endIndex))
```

or

```
welcome = String(welcome.dropLast())
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to trim the last character of the string is:

```
title = title[title.startIndex ..< title.endIndex.advancedBy(-1)]
```

Comment: Thank you, a very elegant way to remove as many characters as you want from the end of a string.

Answer (score 4):

```
import UIKit

var str1 = "Hello, playground"
str1.removeLast()
print(str1)

var str2 = "Hello, playground"
str2.removeLast(3)
print(str2)

var str3 = "Hello, playground"
str3.removeFirst(2)
print(str3)

Output:-
Hello, playgroun
Hello, playgro
llo, playground
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let str = "abc"
let substr = str.substringToIndex(str.endIndex.predecessor())  // "ab"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

extension String {
    var stringByDeletingLastCharacter: String {
        return dropLast(self)
    }
}

println(str.stringByDeletingLastCharacter)   // "Hello, playgroun"
```

Comment: kkkk I didn't even remember of this one (Swift 1.2 above).  for Swift 3 version  http://stackoverflow.com/a/40028338/2303865

Answer (score 2):

Short answer (valid as of 2015-04-16): **`removeAtIndex(myString.endIndex.predecessor())`**

Example:

```
var howToBeHappy = "Practice compassion, attention and gratitude. And smile!!"
howToBeHappy.removeAtIndex(howToBeHappy.endIndex.predecessor())
println(howToBeHappy)
// "Practice compassion, attention and gratitude. And smile!"
```

Meta:

The language continues its rapid evolution, making the half-life for many formerly-good S.O. answers dangerously brief. It's always best to learn the language and refer to real [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html).

Answer (score 2):

With the new Substring type usage:

### Swift 4:

```
var before: String = "Hello world!"
var lastCharIndex: Int = before.endIndex
var after:String = String(before[..<lastCharIndex])
print(after) // Hello world
```

Shorter way:

```
var before: String = "Hello world!"
after = String(before[..<before.endIndex])
print(after) // Hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `advance(startIndex, endIndex)`:

```
var str = "45+22"
str = str.substringToIndex(advance(str.startIndex, countElements(str) - 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

A swift category that's mutating:

```
extension String {
    mutating func removeCharsFromEnd(removeCount:Int)
    {
        let stringLength = count(self)
        let substringIndex = max(0, stringLength - removeCount)
        self = self.substringToIndex(advance(self.startIndex, substringIndex))
    }
}
```

Use:

```
var myString = "abcd"
myString.removeCharsFromEnd(2)
println(myString) // "ab"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way If you want to remove **one or more** than one character from the end.

```
var myStr = "Hello World!"
myStr = (myStr as NSString).substringToIndex((myStr as NSString).length-XX)
```

Where **XX** is the number of characters you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 (according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)) 20th Nov 2016

```
let range = expression.index(expression.endIndex, offsetBy: -numberOfCharactersToRemove)..<expression.endIndex
expression.removeSubrange(range)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dropLast()` function removes the last element of the string.

```
var expression = "45+22"
expression = expression.dropLast()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

I also delete my last character from String (i.e. **UILabel text**) in IOS app

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelText: UILabel! // Do Connection with UILabel

@IBAction func whenXButtonPress(_ sender: UIButton) { // Do Connection With X Button

    labelText.text = String((labelText.text?.dropLast())!) // Delete the last caracter and assign it

}
```

[image: IOS APP StoryBoard]

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using NSString for strings that you want to manipulate. Actually come to think of it as a developer I've never run into a problem with NSString that Swift String would solve... I understand the subtleties. But I've yet to have an actual need for them.

```
var foo = someSwiftString as NSString
```

or

```
var foo = "Foo" as NSString
```

or

```
var foo: NSString = "blah"
```

And then the whole world of simple NSString string operations is open to you.

As answer to the question

```
// check bounds before you do this, e.g. foo.length > 0
// Note shortFoo is of type NSString
var shortFoo = foo.substringToIndex(foo.length-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

complimentary to the above code I wanted to remove the beginning of the string and could not find a reference anywhere.  Here is how I did it:

```
var mac = peripheral.identifier.description
let range = mac.startIndex..<mac.endIndex.advancedBy(-50)
mac.removeRange(range)  // trim 17 characters from the beginning
let txPower = peripheral.advertisements.txPower?.description
```

This trims 17 characters from the beginning of the string  (he total string length is 67 we advance -50 from the end and there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**: When you want to remove trailing string:

```
func replaceSuffix(_ suffix: String, replacement: String) -> String {
    if hasSuffix(suffix) {
        let sufsize = suffix.count < count ? -suffix.count : 0
        let toIndex = index(endIndex, offsetBy: sufsize)
        return substring(to: toIndex) + replacement
    }
    else
    {
        return self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the below implementation because I don't have to worry even if the string is empty

```
let str = "abc"
str.popLast()

// Prints ab

str = ""
str.popLast() // It returns the Character? which is an optional

// Print <emptystring>
```