# Delete last character in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm creating a simple calculator app and currently struggling at deleting the last character when a my button is tapped. I'm using the `dropLast()` method but I keep getting the error

> Missing Argument for parameter #1 in call

```
@IBAction func onDelPressed (button: UIButton!)  {
     runningNumber = runningNumber.characters.dropLast()
     currentLbl.text = runningNumber
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Swift 4 (Addendum)

In Swift, you can apply `dropLast()` directectly on the `String` instance, no longer invoking `.characters` to access a `CharacterView` of the `String`:

```
var runningNumber = "12345"
runningNumber = String(runningNumber.dropLast())
print(runningNumber) // 1234
```

#### Swift 3 (Original answer)

I'll assume `runningNumber` is a `String` instance. In this case, `runningNumber.characters.dropLast()` is not of type `String`, but a `CharacterView`:

```
let foo = runningNumber.characters.dropLast()
print(type(of: foo)) // CharacterView
```

You need to use the `CharacterView` to instantiate a `String` instance prior to assigning it back to a property of type `String`, e.g.

```
var runningNumber = "12345"
runningNumber = String(runningNumber.characters.dropLast())
print(runningNumber) // 1234
```

I.e., for your case

```
@IBAction func onDelPressed (button: UIButton!)  {
  runningNumber = String(runningNumber.characters.dropLast())
  currentLbl.text = runningNumber
}
```

Comment: @Mike97 if the `String` instance (e.g. `runningNumber`) is only of a single `Character` or is empty (`""`), the resulting `String` instance after applying `dropLast` to the `CharacterView` of it will be an empty `String` (`""`). Applying `dropLast()` to an empty sequence will result in an empty (sub-)sequence. This is what I would expect. How would you define a different result?

Comment: You're right. But, in Xcode8.3 (in Sierra) just works fine while in Xcode8.2 (El Capitan) the same code was printing the last char (in case of only one char). So later I've cleaned the project, deleted the "Developper" folder.. re-run again and now print an empty line as expected. This was odd, sorry.  PS I voted now for this answere ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Remove last char from string/text in swift

```
var str1 = "123456789"
str1.removeLast()
print(str1)
```

output:

12345678