# How to remove space before end of a String in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I have a `String` that has 2 whitespaces and i would like to only remove the last space in the `String` and also remove the last text. `components(separatedBy: " ")` splits test where there is a space which i don't wanna do.

Current Text

```
let teamName = "Aston Villa -1"
```

I would like it to be like this

```
teamName = "Aston Villa"
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `-1`

Comment: This is coming from the backend, so i just can't remove it like that because the text is normally different. All i want to get is the team name. Thats it. I could just split it and add [0] and [1] together but i don't wanna do it that way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove last character from string. Swift language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122288/remove-last-character-from-string-swift-language)

Comment: That was just an example

Comment: You have to be more specific, what can the last number be. Is it always negative, can it be more than one figure, etc.

Comment: It can be anything. Could be a number of a word. All i need to is to remove the second space in the string

Comment: @sk123, please see the link I posted in the above comment. I believe that will answer your question - Thanks

Comment: You can iterate through all chars of the string. When you have a whitespaces safe the index of it. After that get the last index from the saved values and with replacingCharacters(in: <#T##RangeExpression#>, with: <#T##StringProtocol#>) you can only replace the last whitespace.

Comment: That one i just split it and take the first word in the array [0] using `components(separatedBy: " ")`

Comment: There is some uncertainty as to what you are asking exactly so maybe you could update your questions with some more examples, like "Liverpool -1" or "Aston Villa -1 x" if they are relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution with Regular Expression.

```
let teamName = "Aston Villa -1"
let trimmedTeamName = teamName.replacingOccurrences(of: "(?:\\s[^\\s]+)$", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

The pattern searches backwards (`?:`) for a whitespace character (`\\s`) followed by 1 or more non-whitespace characters (`[^\\s]+`) at the end of the string (`$`)

---

Alternatively you can use `range(of` with the `.backwards` option

```
if let rangeOfLastWhiteSpace = teamName.range(of: " ", options: .backwards) {
    let trimmedTeamName = String(teamName[..<rangeOfLastWhiteSpace.lowerBound])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into the array `["Aston", "Villa", "-1"]`. Drop the last element of the array: `["Aston", "Villa"]`. Join the array back together `"Aston Villa"`.

```swift
let fixedTeamName = teamName.split(separator: " ")
    .dropLast()
    .joined(separator: " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
let kutcer = "Aston Villa -1"
kutcer.lastIndex(of: " ").map( kutcer.prefix(upTo:) ) == "Aston Villa" // true
```

…and if you need it as a non-optional `String`:

```swift
kutcer
.lastIndex(of: " ")
.map( kutcer.prefix(upTo:) )
.map(String.init)
?? kutcer
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work, also for one word team names.

```
var teamName = "Aston Villa -1"

var foundSpace = false

while foundSpace == false {
    if teamName.removeLast() == " " {
        foundSpace = true
    }
}

print(teamName) //  "Aston Villa"
```