# How to Substring in Swift

Tags: string, swift, nsstring, substring, indexof

I'm going crazy with **substrings** in **Swift**. I need to get the **actual index** of a "string" inside another string to determine the range of my final output.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029163/finding-index-of-character-in-swift-string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let yourString = "loremipsumSTRINGdolor" as NSString
let range: NSRange = yourString.rangeOfString("STRING")
let lenght =  range.length
let location = range.location
```

This should do.

EDIT: Fix.

Comment: I edited the answer so it should compile now. I couldn't test as i'm not on my computer atm.