# How do I find the last occurrence of a substring in a Swift string?

Tags: string, swift, substring

In Objective-C I used:

```
[@"abc def ghi abc def ghi" rangeOfString:@"c" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
```

But now NSBackWardsSearch seems not to exist. Could anyone provide equivalent code for Swift?

I would like to be able to find the character number in the whole string if possible. So in the example above it would return 3.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Cocoa frameworks should be accessible in Swift, but you need to import them. Try importing `Foundation` to access the NSString API. From "[Working with Cocoa Data Types–Strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_43)" of the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" guide:

> Swift automatically bridges between the String type and the NSString class. [...] To enable string bridging, just import Foundation.

Additionally, `NSBackwardsSearch` is an enum value (marked & imported as an [option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24066170/90527)), so you have to use Swift's enum/option syntax to access it (as part of the `NSStringCompareOptions` option type). Prefixes are stripped from [C enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_13) values, so drop the `NS` from the value name.

Taken all together, we have:

```
import Foundation
"abc def ghi abc def ghi".rangeOfString("c", options:NSStringCompareOptions.BackwardsSearch)
```

Note that you might have to use the [`distance` and `advance`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24056932/90527) functions to properly make use of the range from `rangeOfString`.

Answer (score 40):

And if you want to replace the last substring in a string:

(Swift 3)

```
extension String
{
    func replacingLastOccurrenceOfString(_ searchString: String,
            with replacementString: String,
            caseInsensitive: Bool = true) -> String
    {
        let options: String.CompareOptions
        if caseInsensitive {
            options = [.backwards, .caseInsensitive]
        } else {
            options = [.backwards]
        }

        if let range = self.range(of: searchString,
                options: options,
                range: nil,
                locale: nil) {

            return self.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: replacementString)
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let alphabet = "abc def ghi abc def ghi"
let result = alphabet.replacingLastOccurrenceOfString("ghi",
        with: "foo")

print(result)

// "abc def ghi abc def foo"
```

Or, if you want to remove the last substring completely, and clean it up:

```
let result = alphabet.replacingLastOccurrenceOfString("ghi",
            with: "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

print(result)

// "abc def ghi abc def"
```

Comment: Works perfectly in Swift 4.2 as well.

Comment: nice job. Works perfectly

Answer (score 18):

**Swift 3.0:**

```
"abc def ghi abc def ghi".range(of: "c", options: String.CompareOptions.backwards, range: nil, locale: nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 5:**

```
"abc def ghi abc def ghi".range(of: "c", options: NSString.CompareOptions.backwards)
```

Comment: Using `NSString` instead of `String`, especially in such a late version of Swift, is not recommended. Also, this seems to just replicate the solution given [4 years](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39876601/1974224) before, if you're answering an old question please make sure your answer adds value over the existing ones.