# Swift is there a method that gives the index of a substring inside another string

Tags: string, macos, swift, swift-extensions

Is there any existing function that looks for the index of a substring inside another string? A method like `.indexOfSubstring` thank does this:

```
let word: String = "Hey there, how are you?"

let indexOf: Int = word.indexOfSubstring("ere, how are")

println("index = " + \(indexOf))
```

and prints:

```
index = 6
```

Comment: More or less a duplicate of [Finding index of character in Swift String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029163/finding-index-of-character-in-swift-string). – That question is about finding a *character*, but the answers work for finding strings as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `rangeOfString` method:

```
import Foundation

let word: String = "Hey there, how are you?"

if let range = word.rangeOfString("ere, how are") {
    let index = distance(word.startIndex, range.startIndex)
    println("index = \(index)")
}
```

It returns a range, i.e. both sides of the searched string - just use the `startIndex` property.

Note that this is a method borrowed from `NSString`

Comment: Why it is complaining about 'String' does not have member named 'rangeOfString'? for me

Comment: maybe it should be `range` and not `ranger`, unless it's a typo in your comment :)

Comment: sry It was typing mistake and I copied your code to playground.But still getting this error

Comment: Did you `import Cocoa` ?

Comment: or `import UIKit` if in iOS, or `import Foundation` if not using UI

Comment: @Antonio, you should add the info about `import Foundation`, et al to your answer.

Comment: Note that `range.startIndex` is a `String.Index` and *not* an `Int`. I would suggest `if let range = word.rangeOfString("...") { let index = distance(word.startIndex, range.startIndex) ; println("index = \(index)") } ` .

Comment: Thanks @MartinR. SO wouldn't be the same without you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no build in method in Swift. You will need to implement it yourself. Another implementation of this is

```
/// Get the start index of string
///
/// :return start index of .None if not found
public func indexOf(str: String) -> Int? {
    return self.indexOfRegex(Regex.escapeStr(str))
}

/// Get the start index of regex pattern
///
/// :return start index of .None if not found
public func indexOfRegex(pattern: String) -> Int? {
    if let range = Regex(pattern).rangeOfFirstMatch(self).toRange() {
        return range.startIndex
    }
    return .None
}
```

This code is from this library which has bunch of extensions for common swift types such as String 
https://github.com/ankurp/Dollar.swift/blob/master/Cent/Cent/String.swift#L62

You can checkout the docs on the usage 
http://www.dollarswift.org/#indexof-str-string-int