# How do find the string UITextInput creates(or the length of) in a text field? (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to delete an entire word in a text field when I do a long press on the delete key.

I attempted to run a while loop to check for a space (" "), and then delete any char that did not match space (" ") - but...

1) I am not sure if how I'm attempting to search the text field is correct

2) The way I'm attempting my loop is broken because of that

```
func delLong(){
    var proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy
    while [-1] != " "{
        proxy.deleteBackward()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a find and replace method? Something that finds the string and then replaces it

Comment: Thomas - It freezes my interface currently.
...
TheCamp - No, I'm looking to delete all the characters to the left until it reaches a space " " character.

Comment: So where does `textDocumentProxy` come from?

Comment: I think it's a custom keyboard proxy inside of swift - apples info on the command ... A text document proxy provides textual context to a custom keyboard (which is based on the UIInputViewController class) by way of the keyboard’s textDocumentProxy property.

Comment: I'm just an OSX developer (no IOS) but have you put a print statement inside the loop?

Comment: I think my loop is fundamentally broken because I don't know how to get the value I'm looking for haha - lots more reading I guess ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029163/finding-index-of-character-in-swift-string is the closest I've found so far)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested, but you can try:

```
func delLong(){
    var proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy
    while proxy.hasText() {
        let beforeText = proxy.documentContextBeforeInput
        if beforeText.isEmpty || beforeText.hasSuffix(" ") {
            break
        }
        proxy.deleteBackward()
    }
}
```