# CollectionType Index Behavior

Tags: swift

If I bind an index computed from one collection type, such as a `String`, it seems I can reuse that index for other collections.  For example:

```
var str1 = "Hello, World!"
var dex1 = str1.startIndex

var str2 = "Goodbye, All!"

str2[dex1] => "G"
```

This makes some sense if one thinks of this `String.Index` as an integer offset (into an array); however, an Index as an Integer is far from a requirement.  Yet, many/all builtin Swift collection types: `Array`, `Dictionary`, `Set` and `String` all have these 'reusable' indexes.

**It this 'reuse' across collection types a requirement?**  I've not noted it in any documentation; have I overlooked it?

In the above code example, I had expected:

```
> str2[dex1]
Exception: dex1 is not an index of str2
```

[String is just an example; see the question in bold]

Comment: What's the question? There's nothing "reusable" going on here. The whole concept "If I bind an index computed from one instance" is just fluff. This is just a type like any other type. `str1.startIndex` is, as you rightly say, a `String.Index`. Well, so you can use it wherever a `String.Index` is usable. And subscripting a String is one of the places it is usable. And so on. It isn't "bound" to anything.

Comment: This is a general question about requirements on indices.  If I create a Tree type with parent/child nodes and I base the indexing on walking the nodes... then the root node/index in one tree *won't* be useable in another tree.

Comment: Why won't it be usable? A type is a type. Your "not an index of str2" is just something you're making up for no reason. It might be out of range but it is still a value of the right type.

Comment: Ranges (and indices) created for one string cannot be reliably used for a different string, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24056932/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR I didn't say it was reliable. I said it was usable, i.e. syntactically legal. Naturally this will crash: `"x"[advance("hello".startIndex,1)]` But it isn't illegal and there's nothing surprising about that. It is a silly thing to do, but there is nothing about the nature of `String.Index` that makes it surprising that you can do it.

Comment: @matt: My comment was more directed to OP than to you. And the example that I had in mind (from the referenced thread) is `let x = ""[advance("hello".startIndex,1)]` which produces garbage (because advancing by 1 in "hello" does something different than advancing by 1 in "").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, from the Apple forums, summarizing: The observed behavior:

- is not a requirement
- should not be relied upon
- for value types, it may be difficult to throw an exception

Comment: I've noticed that they have figured out to throw an exception in the one case where you use `endIndex` as a subscript or try to advance positively beyond it, so clearly it is marked in a special way. But otherwise this definitely accords with what we were getting at in the comments, namely, this is not really surprising but don't do it.