# Index of a substring in a string with Swift

Tags: swift, string, substring

I'm used to do this in JavaScript:

```
var domains = "abcde".substring(0, "abcde".indexOf("cd")) // Returns "ab"
```

Swift doesn't have this function, how to do something similar?

Comment: @eric-d This is not a duplicate of the one you've mentioned. The OP is about indexOf() and not substring().

Comment: In Swift 2 there is a String.rangeOfString(String) method that returns a Range.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

edit/update:

**Xcode 11.4 • Swift 5.2 or later**

```
import Foundation

extension StringProtocol {
    func index<S: StringProtocol>(of string: S, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> Index? {
        range(of: string, options: options)?.lowerBound
    }
    func endIndex<S: StringProtocol>(of string: S, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> Index? {
        range(of: string, options: options)?.upperBound
    }
    func indices<S: StringProtocol>(of string: S, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> [Index] {
        ranges(of: string, options: options).map(\.lowerBound)
    }
    func ranges<S: StringProtocol>(of string: S, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> [Range<Index>] {
        var result: [Range<Index>] = []
        var startIndex = self.startIndex
        while startIndex < endIndex,
            let range = self[startIndex...]
                .range(of: string, options: options) {
                result.append(range)
                startIndex = range.lowerBound < range.upperBound ? range.upperBound :
                    index(range.lowerBound, offsetBy: 1, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

---

**usage:**

```
let str = "abcde"
if let index = str.index(of: "cd") {
    let substring = str[..<index]   // ab
    let string = String(substring)
    print(string)  // "ab\n"
}
```

---

```
let str = "Hello, playground, playground, playground"
str.index(of: "play")      // 7
str.endIndex(of: "play")   // 11
str.indices(of: "play")    // [7, 19, 31]
str.ranges(of: "play")     // [{lowerBound 7, upperBound 11}, {lowerBound 19, upperBound 23}, {lowerBound 31, upperBound 35}]
```

---

case insensitive sample

```
let query = "Play"
let ranges = str.ranges(of: query, options: .caseInsensitive)
let matches = ranges.map { str[$0] }   //
print(matches)  // ["play", "play", "play"]
```

---

regular expression sample

```
let query = "play"
let escapedQuery = NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: query)
let pattern = "\\b\(escapedQuery)\\w+"  // matches any word that starts with "play" prefix

let ranges = str.ranges(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression)
let matches = ranges.map { str[$0] }

print(matches) //  ["playground", "playground", "playground"]
```

Comment: This isn't quite right, as `"ab".indexOf("a")` and `"ab".indexOf("c")` both return `0`.

Comment: and for those that have upgraded to Swift 3.0:  extension String {
  
    func indexOf(string: String) -> String.Index? {
        return range(of: string, options: .literal, range: nil, locale: nil)?.lowerBound
    }  }

Comment: **Make sure you** `import Foundation` **or this will not work.** Because really you're just using NSString at this point.

Comment: `range: nil`  and  `locale: nil` can be omitted, those parameters have a default value `nil`.

Comment: This is a ton of work - and not the Swift native way. See @Inder Kumar Rathore's answer below - simple use of '.range( of: "text" )' method

Comment: @Marchy kkkk his answer it is exactly the same as mine but limited to the first occurrence

Comment: Getting this message - String has no member ranges. Anything on this?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey are you sure your extension is added correctly to your project? have you tried your code in playground?

Comment: With **Swift 4.2** you need to do `str.index(of: "play")?.encodedOffset` to get 7

Comment: @lewis https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540185/how-to-convert-index-to-type-int-in-swift/34540310#comment98673377_52397384

Comment: @LeoDabus in C++, python you got string.find routine, why the f do you have to always extend the language in SWIFT yourself? Almost all the solutions around swift questions relate to writing own extensions.

Comment: What routine is that? Does it find only the first occurrence or all of them?

Comment: in C++, python you can optionally pass additional position parameter, finding all occurrences ridiculously straightforward: string.find(substring, idx_firstoccurence+1)

Comment: @YuZ you can do exactly the same in Swift using `index(after:)`. So you are just complaining that Swift collection is not integer based.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238958/discussion-between-yuz-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: How do I get the result as an int I can work with properly? If I print the result of your `str.index(of: "play")` example in Playground (Swift 5, Xcode 14.2), then I get something weird like `Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 458765)`.

Comment: String is not indexed by Int. If you need the distance from startIndex you need to use collection’s distance method

Comment: @Neph [How to convert "Index" to type "Int" in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34540310/2303865)

Answer (score 70):

Using **`String[Range<String.Index>]`** subscript you can get the sub string. You need starting index and last index to create the range and you can do it as below

```
let str = "abcde"
if let range = str.range(of: "cd") {
  let substring = str[..<range.lowerBound] // or str[str.startIndex..<range.lowerBound]
  print(substring)  // Prints ab
}
else {
  print("String not present")
}
```

If you don't define the start index this operator `..<` , it take the starting index. You can also use `str[str.startIndex..<range.lowerBound]` instead of `str[..<range.lowerBound]`

Answer (score 38):

**Swift 5**

Find index of substring

```
let str = "abcdecd"
if let range: Range<String.Index> = str.range(of: "cd") {
    let index: Int = str.distance(from: str.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
    print("index: ", index) //index: 2
}
else {
    print("substring not found")
}
```

Find index of Character

```
let str = "abcdecd"
if let firstIndex = str.firstIndex(of: "c") {
    let index = str.distance(from: str.startIndex, to: firstIndex)
    print("index: ", index)   //index: 2
}
else {
    print("symbol not found")
}
```

Answer (score 8):

## In Swift 4 :

#### Getting Index of a character in a string :

```
let str = "abcdefghabcd"
if let index = str.index(of: "b") {
   print(index) // Index(_compoundOffset: 4, _cache: Swift.String.Index._Cache.character(1))
}
```

#### Creating SubString (prefix and suffix) from String using Swift 4:

```
let str : String = "ilike"
for i in 0...str.count {
    let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: i) // String.Index
    let prefix = str[..<index] // String.SubSequence
    let suffix = str[index...] // String.SubSequence
    print("prefix \(prefix), suffix : \(suffix)")
}
```

#### Output

```
prefix , suffix : ilike
prefix i, suffix : like
prefix il, suffix : ike
prefix ili, suffix : ke
prefix ilik, suffix : e
prefix ilike, suffix :
```

#### If you want to generate a substring between 2 indices , use :

```
let substring1 = string[startIndex...endIndex] // including endIndex
let subString2 = string[startIndex..<endIndex] // excluding endIndex
```

Comment: What is `_compoundOffset`, the number of bytes in the string until that point?

Comment: This is extremely inefficient. It will offset the string from the start index on every iteration. You should simply keep the index position and get the index(after:) on each iteration. Note also that `string[startIndex...endIndex]` would crash. Btw Swift 5 or later you can use `PartialRangeFrom` subscript `let substring1 = str[str.startIndex...]`

Answer (score 7):

Doing this in Swift is possible but it takes more lines, here is a function `indexOf()` doing what is expected:

```
func indexOf(source: String, substring: String) -> Int? {
    let maxIndex = source.characters.count - substring.characters.count
    for index in 0...maxIndex {
        let rangeSubstring = source.startIndex.advancedBy(index)..<source.startIndex.advancedBy(index + substring.characters.count)
        if source.substringWithRange(rangeSubstring) == substring {
            return index
        }
    }
    return nil
}

var str = "abcde"
if let indexOfCD = indexOf(str, substring: "cd") {
    let distance = str.startIndex.advancedBy(indexOfCD)
    print(str.substringToIndex(distance)) // Returns "ab"
}
```

This function is not optimized but it does the job for short strings.

Comment: Its extremely frustrating that they haven't added this to the Swift libraries yet!

Comment: Im adding an `extension String` to  a utils.swift class that will need to be available to all others

Comment: btw the above appears to be `O(N^2)` in the length of the string .. ?

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5**

```
   let alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    var index: Int = 0
    
    if let range: Range<String.Index> = alphabet.range(of: "c") {
         index = alphabet.distance(from: alphabet.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
        print("index: ", index) //index: 2
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34540310/2303865 Note that String indices is not integer based. You won't be able to use it to subscript the collection and access the elements (a character or a substring)

Answer (score 4):

There are three closely connected issues here:

- All the substring-finding methods are over in the Cocoa NSString world (Foundation)
- Foundation NSRange has a mismatch with Swift Range; the former uses start and length, the latter uses endpoints
- In general, Swift characters are indexed using `String.Index`, not Int, but Foundation characters *are* indexed using Int, and there is no simple direct translation between them (because Foundation and Swift have different ideas of what constitutes a character)

Given all that, let's think about how to write:

```
func substring(of s: String, from:Int, toSubstring s2 : String) -> Substring? {
    // ?
}
```

The substring `s2` must be sought in `s` using a String Foundation method. The resulting range comes back to us, *not* as an NSRange (even though this is a Foundation method), but as a Range of `String.Index` (wrapped in an Optional, in case we didn't find the substring at all). However, the other number, `from`, is an Int. Thus we cannot form any kind of range involving them both.

But we don't have to! All we have to do is slice off the *end* of our original string using a method that takes a `String.Index`, and slice off the *start* of our original string using a method that takes an Int. Fortunately, such methods exist! Like this:

```
func substring(of s: String, from:Int, toSubstring s2 : String) -> Substring? {
    guard let r = s.range(of:s2) else {return nil}
    var s = s.prefix(upTo:r.lowerBound)
    s = s.dropFirst(from)
    return s
}
```

Or, if you prefer to be able to apply this method directly to a string, like this...

```
let output = "abcde".substring(from:0, toSubstring:"cd")
```

...then make it an extension on String:

```
extension String {
    func substring(from:Int, toSubstring s2 : String) -> Substring? {
        guard let r = self.range(of:s2) else {return nil}
        var s = self.prefix(upTo:r.lowerBound)
        s = s.dropFirst(from)
        return s
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this copying the original string?  What if the original string were lengthy and this were a repeated operation?  That can be done with zero data copy in the jvm world.

Comment: @javadba No copying in deriving a Substring, that's the whole point of a Substring. Basically that code just walks a bunch of pointers.

Comment: OK - I see the `dropFirst` and have not looked at how that's implemented.     How can we extract the final returning `Substring` into just a `String` ?  I'm seeing super lengthy posts *just on that* ..

Comment: Just coerce to a String. I'm not sure whether there's a copy at that point; there might not be, as long as neither this nor the original string is modified, but I'm unclear on the details of how String adopts copy-on-write.

Comment: ok thx - coercion here we go. I'm getting warning "Cast from Substring to String always fails" when doing `as! String`

Comment: Right, that's a cast, not a coercion. A coercion is `String(theSubstring)`.

Comment: oh!  thx for that. I did not even recognize the distinction of the `cast` / `coercion` term as such on the `jvm`

Comment: @javadba In Swift, you can only cast a thing to a type that it already is. Coercion is when you transform a thing to a different type (which you do by creating an instance of the other type).

Comment: Yes I get that: for `jvm` I would say "create a `String` out of it" or "do a `toString()`" - vs "cast it to a `String`" e.g. via `asInstanceOf[String]` (scala).  But the former lacked a tidy specific term. now we have `coercion`

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**

```
    extension String {
    enum SearchDirection {
        case first, last
    }
    func characterIndex(of character: Character, direction: String.SearchDirection) -> Int? {
        let fn = direction == .first ? firstIndex : lastIndex
        if let stringIndex: String.Index = fn(character) {
            let index: Int = distance(from: startIndex, to: stringIndex)
            return index
        }  else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

tests:

```
 func testFirstIndex() {
        let res = ".".characterIndex(of: ".", direction: .first)
        XCTAssert(res == 0)
    }
    func testFirstIndex1() {
        let res = "12345678900.".characterIndex(of: "0", direction: .first)
        XCTAssert(res == 9)
    }
    func testFirstIndex2() {
        let res = ".".characterIndex(of: ".", direction: .last)
        XCTAssert(res == 0)
    }
    func testFirstIndex3() {
        let res = "12345678900.".characterIndex(of: "0", direction: .last)
        XCTAssert(res == 10)
    }
```

Comment: Adding `String.` prefix inside a String extension is redundant. `SearchDirection`
  would suffice. Note also that Swift is a type inferred language. No need to explicitly set the resulting type if it is not generic.

Answer (score 2):

In the Swift version 3, String doesn't have functions like -

```
str.index(of: String)
```

If the index is required for a substring, one of the ways to is to get the range. We have the following functions in the string which returns range -

```
str.range(of: <String>)
str.rangeOfCharacter(from: <CharacterSet>)
str.range(of: <String>, options: <String.CompareOptions>, range: <Range<String.Index>?>, locale: <Locale?>)
```

For example to find the indexes of first occurrence of play in str

```
var str = "play play play"
var range = str.range(of: "play")
range?.lowerBound //Result : 0
range?.upperBound //Result : 4
```

Note : range is an optional. If it is not able to find the String it will make it nil. For example

```
var str = "play play play"
var range = str.range(of: "zoo") //Result : nil
range?.lowerBound //Result : nil
range?.upperBound //Result : nil
```

Answer (score 2):

Leo Dabus's answer is great. Here is my answer based on his answer using `compactMap` to avoid `Index out of range` error.

### Swift 5.1

```swift
extension StringProtocol {
    func ranges(of targetString: Self, options: String.CompareOptions = [], locale: Locale? = nil) -> [Range<String.Index>] {

        let result: [Range<String.Index>] = self.indices.compactMap { startIndex in
            let targetStringEndIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy: targetString.count, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
            return range(of: targetString, options: options, range: startIndex..<targetStringEndIndex, locale: locale)
        }
        return result
    }
}

// Usage
let str = "Hello, playground, playground, playground"
let ranges = str.ranges(of: "play")
ranges.forEach {
    print("[\($0.lowerBound.utf16Offset(in: str)), \($0.upperBound.utf16Offset(in: str))]")
}

// result - [7, 11], [19, 23], [31, 35]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using NSRange?

```
if let range = mainString.range(of: mySubString) {
  //...
}
```