# get all ranges of a substring in a string in swift

Tags: ios, swift, matching

I have a string for example "ab ad adk fda kla kad ab ab kd". I want to get all range of ab.(Here ab is present at 3 position so I should get 3 range).In normal scenarion my code is working fine, but if search text is ".",then I am getting wrong result

```
do {
    let regEx = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchText, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)

    let matchesRanges = regEx.matchesInString(attributedText.string, options:[], range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.string.length))

    for rng in matchesRanges {
        let wordRange = rng.rangeAtIndex(0)
    }
} catch {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You need to show what you've tried and explain what it does wrong

Comment: please explain in detail  what result you want ?

Comment: A `.` is a special character meaning 'Any character'

Comment: Do you know what regular expressions are? This is not plain old character-by-character string search...

Answer (score 21):

The following solution uses the native Swift 4 function `range(of:, options:, range:, locale:)`):

```
extension String {
    func ranges(of substring: String, options: CompareOptions = [], locale: Locale? = nil) -> [Range<Index>] {
        var ranges: [Range<Index>] = []
        while ranges.last.map({ $0.upperBound < self.endIndex }) ?? true,
            let range = self.range(of: substring, options: options, range: (ranges.last?.upperBound ?? self.startIndex)..<self.endIndex, locale: locale)
        {
            ranges.append(range)
        }
        return ranges
    }
}
```

(Swift 4 then provides native API to convert from `Range<Index>` to `NSRange`)

Comment: This can result in an infinite loop in some situations when using a regular expression. Check this answer on how to avoid it https://stackoverflow.com/a/32306142/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus I've identified one case where that could happen, as indeed some regular expression **will** return a valid range, even if the range to search in is empty. I've updated the code to reflect that. If that was not your original issue, would you mind sharing the regex that caused the issue?

Comment: If I remember correctly it happens if there is an empty range in the end of the string. Sorry but the question/regex I couldn't find.

Comment: @LeoDabus I see, no worries, the edit I made should be good to fix the issue then ;)

Answer (score 20):

**Swift 5:**

The improved version of the most popular answer:

```
extension String {    
    func ranges(of substring: String, options: CompareOptions = [], locale: Locale? = nil) -> [Range<Index>] {
        var ranges: [Range<Index>] = []
        while let range = range(of: substring, options: options, range: (ranges.last?.upperBound ?? self.startIndex)..<self.endIndex, locale: locale) {
            ranges.append(range)
        }
        return ranges
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest such a solution:

```
import Foundation

extension String {

    func rangesOfString(s: String) -> [Range<Index>] {
        let re = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: NSRegularExpression.escapedPatternForString(s), options: [])
        return re.matchesInString(self, options: [], range: nsRange(startIndex ..< endIndex)).flatMap { range($0.range) }
    }

    func range(nsRange : NSRange) -> Range<Index>? {
        let utf16from = utf16.startIndex.advancedBy(nsRange.location, limit: utf16.endIndex)
        let utf16to   = utf16from.advancedBy(nsRange.length, limit: utf16.endIndex)

        if let from = String.Index(utf16from, within: self),
           let to   = String.Index(utf16to,   within: self)
        {
            return from ..< to
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func nsRange(range : Range<Index>) -> NSRange {
        let utf16from = String.UTF16View.Index(range.startIndex, within: utf16)
        let utf16to   = String.UTF16View.Index(range.endIndex,   within: utf16)
        return NSRange(location: utf16.startIndex.distanceTo(utf16from), length: utf16from.distanceTo(utf16to))
    }

}

print("[^x]? [^x]? [^x]?".rangesOfString("[^x]?")) // [Range(0..<5), Range(6..<11), Range(12..<17)]
```

Aside the main question, this code also shows the way to convert `NSRange` to and from `Range<String.Index>` (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30404532/3541063)).

Comment: Does it take care of all other special characters.?

Comment: I use [NSRegularExpression.escapedPatternForString()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSRegularExpression/escapedPatternForString:) to escape any possible pattern metacharacters. This must be a reliable solution.

Comment: Those Range <-> NSRange conversions look familiar http://stackoverflow.com/a/30404532/1187415 :)

Comment: That is probably the right origin. I've added the reference to the post.

Answer (score 1):

You are using regular expressions, so you need to take care about characters that have special meaning - `.` is only one of them.

If you're doing a search for substrings, I suggest to use the good old rangeOf... methods instead:

```
func rangeOfString(_ searchString: String,
           options mask: NSStringCompareOptions,
             range searchRange: NSRange) -> NSRange
```

Just keep calling that method on your string (and adjust the `searchRange`), until no further matches are found.

Answer (score 0):

You can get occurance count for particular string by following code:

```
let str: NSMutableString = "ab ad adk fda kla kad ab ab kd"
let count = str.replaceOccurrencesOfString("ab", withString: "ab", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length))
```

Comment: No I want to get the ranges , so that can apply attributes on that ranges.