# Find Array of Rang of substring in NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I have a attributed string with *$* sign like this " price 1 $ 25 \n price 2 $\n price 3 $" I want find all the ranges of *"$"*

```
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " price 1 $ 25 \n price 2 $\n price 3 $")
let ranges = // all ranges for $ sign
```

I need to set different color for "$".

I know how to find range in attributed string.

```
extension NSAttributedString {
func rangeOf(string: String) -> Range<String.Index>? {
    return self.string.range(of: string)
}}
```

I am wondering how I can find an array of ranges of *"$"* sign in a given attributed string?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865443/get-all-ranges-of-a-substring-in-a-string-in-swift

Comment: It may be a better idea to use NSRegularExpression than using String/NSString here :0

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy with a roundtrip to `AttributedString`:

```swift
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " price 1 $ 25 \n price 2 $\n price 3 $")

let attributedString = AttributedString(attrString)
let substring = "$"

// Iterating through all the occurrences of `substring`.
for range in attributedString.characters.ranges(of: substring) {
   // Do something with the current range
   attributedString[range].foregroundColor = .red
}

let response = NSAttributedString(attributedString)
```