# How get range from regex matches

Tags: swift, regex, range

I'm looking for a way to get the ranges from a regex match. I have a string

> I'm looking for @{1 | Tom Lofe} and @{2 | Cristal Dawn}

From this string, I need to get the ranges of these matches using the following regex

```
"@\\{(\\d+) ?\\| ?(\\w+ *?\\w*?)\\}"
```

What is the best way to do this? So far I've only been able to get the matches but not the ranges. Apparently, the standard Swift function `range(of: <#T##StringProtocol#>, options: <#T##String.CompareOptions#>, range: <#T##Range<String.Index>?#>, locale: <#T##Locale?#>)` should be able to do this, but I don't know how to use it, and can't seem to find a good example.

I've also tried this question's answer [get all ranges of a substring in a string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865443/get-all-ranges-of-a-substring-in-a-string-in-swift) but again am unable to get it to work.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305891/index-of-a-substring-in-a-string-with-swift You can use `ranges(of:)` with `options: .regularExpression`

Comment: Are you happy to mark my answer as correct as, I believe, it satisfies your original question and the subsequent variant raised. Thanks. Good question, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in an Xcode Playground, but let me know if it doesn't work for you.

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "@\\{(\\d+) ?\\| ?(\\w+ *?\\w*?)\\}", options: [])

let input = "I'm looking for @{1 | Tom Lofe} and @{2 | Cristal Dawn}"
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: input.utf16.count)

for match in regex.matches(in: input, options: [], range: range) {
    print(match.range)
}
```

Prints:

```
{16, 15}
{36, 19}
```

Comment: Try this with `let input = "I'm looking for @{1 | Tom Lofe} and @{2 | Cristal Dawn}"`

Comment: I’m not sure I understand, @MartinR   Is this is a different question now?

Comment: @ScottMcKenzie you are using the wrong value for the length. you need to pass the utf16 count. `NSRange(location: 0, length: input.utf16.count)`

Comment: Did you try it? Did you notice that only one range is printed? – You'll find an explanation in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27880748/1187415

Comment: @ScottMcKenzie Well I am showing to you what's wrong in your code. Feel free to keep your answer as it is if you would like to. Btw , `options: []` is the default value therefore you can just omit it.

Comment: Sorry @LeoDabus, I get that. But my answer was for the original question. Updating for unicode characters is, as you say. Answer amended.

Comment: @MartinR Try now.