# find first occurrence of string starting at given index

Tags: ios, swift

I want to find the first occurrence of string starting at given index.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32306142/386738) I have created following function:

```
func index(of string: String, from startIndex: String.Index? = nil, options: String.CompareOptions = .literal) -> String.Index? {
    if let startIndex = startIndex {
        return range(of: string, options: options, range: startIndex ..< string.endIndex, locale: nil)?.lowerBound
    } else {
        return range(of: string, options: options, range: nil, locale: nil)?.lowerBound
    }
}
```

unfortunately, the part with the index doesn't work.

For example following code returns `nil` instead of `3`:

```
let str = "test"
str.index(of: "t", from: str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
```

Comment: You are limiting the search to the wrong range. `string.endIndex` should be `self.endIndex` (or just `endIndex`).

Comment: Like always, you are right @MartinR. Now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are limiting the search to the wrong range. `string.endIndex` should be `self.endIndex` (or just `endIndex`).

Further remarks:

- `range: nil` and `locale: nil` can be omitted because those
  parameters have default values.
- `String.Index` can be shortened to `Index` inside a `String`
  extension method, similarly for `String.CompareOptions`.
- I would not call the optional parameter `startIndex` as that causes
  confusion with the `startIndex` property of `String`.

Putting it all together:

```
extension String {
    func index(of string: String, from startPos: Index? = nil, options: CompareOptions = .literal) -> Index? {
        if let startPos = startPos {
            return range(of: string, options: options, range: startPos ..< endIndex)?.lowerBound
        } else {
            return range(of: string, options: options)?.lowerBound
        }
    }
}
```

or alternatively

```
extension String {
    func index(of string: String, from startPos: Index? = nil, options: CompareOptions = .literal) -> Index? {
        let startPos = startPos ?? startIndex
        return range(of: string, options: options, range: startPos ..< endIndex)?.lowerBound
    }
}
```