# How to separate two URLs in a String in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

What is the best way to split this String into two using Swift?

```
"https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/http://nusoft.fnal.gov/nova/public/img/FD-evt-echo.gif"
```

I only need the second part of url in the String. In this example, in this case I just need:

```
"http://nusoft.fnal.gov/nova/public/img/FD-evt-echo.gif"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Split String Using Regex Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476395/how-to-split-string-using-regex-expressions)

Comment: Hi Samuel, you should write logic to fix this error which is from Nasa APOD API. This is already opened in their Github [repo](https://github.com/nasa/apod-api/issues/6) Check and keep follow the issue so you will get to know when there'll be an update.

Answer (score 1):

```
let str = "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/http://nusoft.fnal.gov/nova/public/img/FD-evt-echo.gif"

if let lastStr = str.components(separatedBy: "http").last
{      
    let result = "http" + lastStr
    print(result) 
}
```

Console Output: http://nusoft.fnal.gov/nova/public/img/FD-evt-echo.gif