# Swift - Splitting strings with regex - ignoring search string

Tags: regex, swift4, nsregularexpression

There is a clever 1st answer given here for splitting swift string with a regex expression

[split string answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476395/how-to-split-string-using-regex-expressions)

However it keeps the searched text within the array of answers. I'm trying to do a similar thing, but ignoring the characters acting as separators (e.g. just like the swift split function, but just with a regex expression as the separator).

As an example: regex would be something like

```
"\\\||Z|ZY"
```

and when applied to string of `"hi|thisZshouldZYbe|separated"` then you would get back an array

```
["hi", "this", "should", "be", "separated"]
```

NB. The regex is adapted to the swift NSRegularExpression format with the double escape. In regular regex it would just be "\||Z|ZY"
Also NB the regex contains the vertical line symbol not the letter "l"

You prob don't need to do too many tweaks to the original to make work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define an extension like this:

```
extension String {
    func split(usingRegex pattern: String) -> [String] {
        //### Crashes when you pass invalid `pattern`
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
        let matches = regex.matches(in: self, range: NSRange(0..<utf16.count))
        let ranges = [startIndex..<startIndex] + matches.map{Range($0.range, in: self)!} + [endIndex..<endIndex]
        return (0...matches.count).map {String(self[ranges[$0].upperBound..<ranges[$0+1].lowerBound])}
    }
}

let str = "hi|thisZshouldZYbe|separated"
let separator = "\\||ZY?"
let result = str.split(usingRegex: separator)
print(result) //->["hi", "this", "should", "be", "separated"]
```

The above code does not work as you expect when you use `"\\||Z|ZY"`, but I think you can modify your pattern to fit into this extension.

Comment: Thank you. I think I can follow what you've done in the code - and makes sense. Very concise! and I didn't realise you could use map like that on the return statement - so many thanks. It's this conversion between NSRanges and normal ranges which makes it so tricky. I need to test once some other errors corrected.

Comment: I've tested this and it is working well for my purposes. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to create an UUID string as separator, then replace the occurrences of the regex pattern with this UUID string and split the string.

```
let string = "hi|thisZshouldZYbe|separated"
let uuid = UUID().uuidString
let result = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\||ZY?", with: uuid, options: .regularExpression).components(separatedBy: uuid)
```

Your pattern works only in another order of the OR parts (`"\\||ZY|Z"`)

Comment: Why not use `UUID` in Swift?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, why not? 