# How do I split string using some condition and separator

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a [String] that goes like

> ABC,JKL,123,12,PQR
>
> ABC,"XY, Z",654,54,PQR

The resulting array should look like this:

> ["ABC","JKL","123","12",PQR],["ABC","XY, Z","654","54","PQR"]

This is what I have tried already, but this does not work as I want in second element's case:

```
content.components(separatedBy: "\n").map{ $0.components(separatedBy: ",") }
```

Comment: That's great. What have you tried so far to accomplish this?

Comment: as of now I am using -> content.components(separatedBy: "\n").map{ $0.components(separatedBy: ",") } , but this does not work as I want in second element's case

Answer (score 0):

## Idea behind solution:

You want to split your string into an array on every occurrence of `,`, accounting for data contained within `"` as a single item.

To do this you have to use the global [`split` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476395/how-to-split-string-using-regex-expressions) with a [regex pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356259/kotlin-string-split-ignore-when-delimiter-is-inside-a-quote).

## Code sample:

```swift
extension String
{
  func splitCommas() -> [Stirng] {
    let pattern = ",(?=(?:[^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*\$)" //regex pattern for commas that are not within quotes
    if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: []) {
      let string = self as NSString
      return regex.matches(in:inputString, range: NSMakeRange(0, inputString.utf16.count)).map {
        string.substring(with: $0.range).replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "") //removing all instances of commas
      }
    }
    return []
  }
}
```

Hope this helps! ;)

## Updates

[Updated code to more modern example.](https://learnappmaking.com/regular-expressions-swift-string/)

Also implemented function as a String extension for usability within all of the String variables.

Comment: What version of swift is this?

Comment: Tamil Nadu,Tenkasi ,"MANMATHAN,M.",M,60,SC,IND,3331,0,1382081 -> [",Tenkasi ", ",\"MANMATHAN,M.\"", ",M", ",60", ",SC", ",IND", ",3331", ",0", ",1382081"]. Nope

Comment: @KishanSadhwani, can't you post proper test data in your question so we understand what kind of strings we are dealing with?

Comment: @KishanSadhwani If I understood it correctly, it seems like the first string (`Tamil Nadu`) is missing and the output array still has the commas in them?