# Regex g is for global search

Tags: swift

I am using:

```
var test = "pizzazz"

if let match = test.range(of: "g/zz", options: .regularExpression) {
    print(test.substring(with: match))
}
```

This 
How do I set g for global search?

Comment: it's global by default

Comment: But "zz" only gives me "zz" There should be two - that is two ranges

Comment: Because you only asked for a single match

Comment: Ok, I guess I have to use NSRegularExpression then. Like this on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32306142/2303865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what should be the result of your example, but you are probably looking for one of these functions:

1)

```
func enumerateMatches(in string: String, 
              options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions = [], 
                range: NSRange, 
                using block: (NSTextCheckingResult?, NSRegularExpression.MatchingFlags, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void)
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpression/1409687-enumeratematches

2)

```
func matches(in string: String, 
         options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions = [], 
           range: NSRange) -> [NSTextCheckingResult]
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpression/1412446-matches

3)

```
func stringByReplacingMatches(in string: String, 
                      options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions = [], 
                        range: NSRange, 
                 withTemplate templ: String) -> String
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpression/1413740-stringbyreplacingmatches

4)

```
func replaceMatches(in string: NSMutableString, 
            options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions = [], 
              range: NSRange, 
       withTemplate templ: String) -> Int
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpression/1411139-replacematches