# Cannot convert value of type 'subSequence' (aka 'String.CharacterView') to type 'String' in collection

Tags: swift, string

I build a webservis that requesting image url from the database. And I want to show it on the swift. But I'm gettig this error on the var photo line:

> Cannot convert value of type 'subSequence' (aka 'String.CharacterView') to type 'String' in collection

```
let requestResponse = self.sendToServer(postUrl: "localhost",data:"abc")

let Seperated = requestResponse.characters.split(separator: " ")

var photo = Seperated[0] as String

let imageURL = URL(string: photo)
if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL!) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `let photo = String(Seperated.first ?? "")`

Comment: split method on the characters returns aa array of String CharacterView SubSequences. You need to initialize a new string with one of them

Answer (score 50):

Consider something like this:

```
let requestResponse = "some string"
let separated = requestResponse.characters.split(separator: " ")

if let some = separated.first {
    let value = String(some)

    // Output: "some"
}
```

Comment: How to get "string" from requestResponse?

Comment: @Satyam see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305891/index-of-a-substring-in-a-string-with-swift. You'll just need to adjust a bit

Answer (score 43):

The easiest solution.

```swift
let separated = requestResponse.characters.split(separator: " ").map { String($0) }
```

Comment: It took me a while to understand why this was neccesary, but it's because split returns a 'substring' object not a string.  It's similar but for speed reasons if you modify a substring it modifies from the original string so it's more memory efficient.  So what map does is for each 'substring' converts it to an actual string, which is necessary for a lot of functions.  Hope this helps someone else understand why this works some more.

Answer (score 11):

If swift 4 you use like this:

```
let separated = requestResponse.split(separator: " ")
var photo = String(separated.first ?? "")
```

Answer (score 9):

`split` returns a list of `Substring`s, so we have to map (convert) them to `String`s. To do that you can just pass the `Substring` to the `String`s `init` function:

```
let separated = requestResponse.characters.split(separator: " ").map(String.init)
```

Comment: swift is not a _bad_ language but it does make many simple things frustrating

Comment: @javadba Gotta agree, mate! :D

Comment: Swift's tight typing is wonderful, because it prevents so many mistakes that Objective-C's complete looseness allowed. However, it does get very frustrating at times (just let me force you to do this - aargh!).

Answer (score 5):

An approach to obtain strings from splitting a string using high order functions:

```
let splitStringArray = requestResponse.split(separator: " ").map({ (substring) in
    return String(substring)
})
```