# How to manipulate existing `String.Index` after the original string has been changed?

Tags: swift

**Background**

I am writing a syntax marker kind of tool in swift. I parse the text, then save the marking info, I call it a `Mark` (a name as a `String` with a range as a `Range<String.Index>`). I choose the `Range<String.Index>` over `NSRange` for future proof the interface.

**Problem**

In order to support on the fly parsing, I need to be able to manipulate the range. E.g. the text has been edited in a text view, instead of re-parse the whole text, I want to only parse the edited chunk for performance gain. The problem is how do I shift the `Marks` after the edited range? Since they are never changed, the only thing that changes are the ranges.

I've tried [the index function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1786175-index) like this:

```
let newStartIndex = string.index(oldStartIndex, offsetBy: changeInLength)
```

But the problem with that is that the `oldStartIndex` is very possible to be out of bound of the new `string`. Then it will throw a fatal error. Even if I kept a copy of the old text and use that to do the index offset, I think the old index within the modified string might not necessarily maintain it's integrity.

With `NSRange`, things are much simpler, just shift the `location` property. But the key here is to future proof the interface by using `Range<String.Index>`.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is more along the lines of a tree structure rather than a linear structure. Maybe something similar to a [parse tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree)? What kind of syntax marking are you doing?

Comment: just manipulate your ranges in reverse order

Comment: @ColGraff [org-mode](http://orgmode.org) syntax. It's not a programming language, but it can get pretty complex. Part of it needs to be a tree structure but it can still be flatten out in a bigger scope. It doesn't matter, the point is to shift `Range<String.Index>`.

Comment: @LeoDabus can you be more specific? An example would be nice.

Comment: If you would like to execute multiple replace/remove using your ranges just iterate from the least occurrence (range) to the first. If you have an array with your string ranges `for range in ranges.reversed() {` you can remove all your string subranges without any issue.

Comment: @LeoDabus but I don't want to remove them, I want to adjust(shift) them. E.g., I have 3 marks, their ranges are: `0..<3`, `3..<6`, `6..<9`, now I deleted 1 char at index 4. the range needs to be `0..<3`, `3..<5`, `5..<8`.

Comment: Does it matter? Whatever you do do it starting at the end

Comment: @LeoDabus Now the problem is how do I shift `6..<9` to `5..<8`. of course the integer in the example is just for illustration purpose, `String.Index` is not a integer.

Comment: you can use index offsetBy to the start and end indexes (lower and upper) and form a new range with it

Comment: if you need some code example on how to use index offsetBy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language/38215613#38215613 and if you need to get your string ranges https://stackoverflow.com/a/32306142/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus I've tried it, to shift the upper of 6..<9, you do string.index(`9`, offsetBy: -1), but your string.characters.count == 8, so `9` is an invalid index. Which is exactly the problem I described in the question.

Comment: Post your code (minimum verifiable example)