# Swift 4 How to find Index of a particular substring in String

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift 4 and practising swift. I am not able to figure out how to find a index of a particular substring inside a string. Below is code :

```
var hello = "Hello This is HelloWorld !"
if let idx = hello.characters.index(of: "!") {
    hello.insert(contentsOf: ", world".characters, at: idx)
}
```

I need a function which return me "HelloWorld" index from var hello. I think there should be inbuilt function but i couldnt find it.  i Have seen this post of stack overflow  [Index of a substring in a string with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305891/index-of-a-substring-in-a-string-with-swift) but most of code is outdated. please help me to sort this .

Comment: so there is no inbuild index of function in swift ?

Comment: it may be duplicate question but solution of post is not working swift 4 as its throwing error "advanceBy is unavailable"

Comment: It is just `if let range = string.range(of: substring) { ... }`, as you can see from the first answer. You don't have to use the custom extensions. That should work in Swift 3 and 4.