# String format parameters binding dictionary

Tags: swift, nspredicate, nsexpression

Is there any built-in solution that allows to substitute strings in a manner of `NSExpression` does (i.e. with a binding dictionary provided)?

So instead of:

```
let s = String(format: "%@ %@", arguments: ["foo", "bar"]) // "foo bar"
```

we have:

```
let s = String(format: "$foo $bar", ["foo": "hello", "bar": "world"]) // hello world
```

P.S. I'm aware of `replaceOccurrences`, I need NSExpression style substitution. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing built-in like that, but nothing prevents you from writing your own method that behaves like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by matt you would need to implement your own method. You can use a regex to match the ranges of all keys of your dictionary that starts with a dollar sign `"\\$\\w+"` and use the method `"ranges(of:)"` of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305891/index-of-a-substring-in-a-string-with-swift/32306142?s=1%7C0.0000#32306142) to replace the subranges of your string creating a custom initializer extending String:

```
extension String {
    init(format: String, _ dictionary: [String: String]) {
        var result = format
        for range in format.ranges(of: "\\$\\w+", options: .regularExpression).reversed() {
            result.replaceSubrange(range, with: dictionary[String(format[range].dropFirst())] ?? "")
        }
        self = result
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let result = String(format: "$foo $bar", ["foo": "hello", "bar": "world"])
print(result)   // "hello world"
```

Comment: Obviously the implementer can decide what is best but it might be a good idea to replace missing keys with something more obvious than the empty string. Perhaps the original key, including the `$` sign. This would make debugging a lot easier since it is much more noticeable.

Comment: @rmaddy I could also just force unwrap and make it crash. He can just add a default value `format[range]` if he wants to

Comment: @LeoDabus how fast is that? Looks pretty legit, but not suitable for UITableView I guess...

Comment: It can't get faster than that