# How to get substring between two known substring in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, string

I have XML error returned from the server, which the snippet of the interest part of the error is like this:

`...`
`<p class="break-long-words trace-message">SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column &quot;name&quot; violates not-null constraint<br />
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (165, null, null, 11, null, 2018-04-19 03:01:48, null, f, 6).</p>`
`...`

Because this happens often during development, I want to make it easier for me to scan for this particular error message and report it to the backend team. So from the error like above, I conclude that I can confidently get the substring that *begins* with `SQLSTATE` and ends *before* `</p>`. So the cleaned error will be:

`SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column &quot;name&quot; violates not-null constraint<br />
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (165, null, null, 11, null, 2018-04-19 03:01:48, null, f, 6).`

The question is, how to do that in Swift? The XML error is not just this only. I just cut out the point of interest. But there will be a plethora of `<p></p>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Using extension found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32306142/300392 I have implemented my own solution:

```
if xml.contains("</p>") {
    let beginIndex = xml.index(of: "SQLSTATE")!
    let result1 = String(xml[beginIndex...]);

    let endIndex = result1.index(of: "</p>")!;
    let endIndexBefore = result1.index(before: endIndex);
    let result2 = String(result1[...endIndexBefore]);

    print ("SQL ERROR: \(result2)");
}
```