# Looking for the best way to filter text from string in Swift

Tags: swift, data-structures

I have an array of Strings in ascending sorted order. I want to filter char/text in that array and get results from searched text letter first and then the rest. I am looking for the simplest way to do this job.          
      
Example:

```
Var array = ["Anand", "Ani", "Dan", "Eion", "Harsh", "Jocab", "Roshan", "Stewart"]
```

and search text is "R"

Output should be:

```
Var outArray = ["Roshan", "Harsh", "Stewart"]
```

Comment: Use the `filter` method?

Comment: I am looking results in order with searched text in 1st place with high priority and then onwards

Comment: So you also want to sort the results based on where the letters appear in the string?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for order as mentioned

Comment: Is the search text always a single character?

Comment: no, It can go to any limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to first map the strings to a tuple containing the index of the search text in string, and the string itself. Then sort by the index, then map the tuples back to the strings.

```
let array = ["Anand", "Ani", "Dan", "Eion", "Harsh", "Jocab", "Roshan", "Stewart"]
let searchText = "R"
// compactMap acts as a filter, removing the strings where string.index(of: searchText, options: [.caseInsensitive]) returns nil
let result = array.compactMap { string in string.index(of: searchText, options: [.caseInsensitive]).map { ($0, string) } }
                    .sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }.map { $0.1 }
```

The `index(of:options:)` method is taken from [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32306142/5133585).

For Swift 4.x:

```
extension StringProtocol where Index == String.Index {
    func index(of string: Self, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> Index? {
        return range(of: string, options: options)?.lowerBound
    }
    func endIndex(of string: Self, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> Index? {
        return range(of: string, options: options)?.upperBound
    }
    func indexes(of string: Self, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> [Index] {
        var result: [Index] = []
        var startIndex = self.startIndex
        while startIndex < endIndex,
            let range = self[startIndex...].range(of: string, options: options) {
                result.append(range.lowerBound)
                startIndex = range.lowerBound < range.upperBound ? range.upperBound :
                    index(range.lowerBound, offsetBy: 1, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
        }
        return result
    }
    func ranges(of string: Self, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> [Range<Index>] {
        var result: [Range<Index>] = []
        var startIndex = self.startIndex
        while startIndex < endIndex,
            let range = self[startIndex...].range(of: string, options: options) {
                result.append(range)
                startIndex = range.lowerBound < range.upperBound ? range.upperBound :
                    index(range.lowerBound, offsetBy: 1, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: I am looking for solution in Swift 4.

Comment: This works in Swift 4.2. @VinitIngale It should work in Swift 4 too.

Comment: index(of:options:) method for Swift 5 or later

Comment: let result = array.compactMap { string in string.lowercased().firstIndex(of: Character(searchText.lowercased())).map { ($0, string) } }
    .sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }.map { $0.1 }  . Try like this.

Comment: @VinitIngale did you read the code in the linked answer? If you scroll to the right, you’ll see that you only need to add a generic constraint to make it work for Swift 4. `Index == String.Index`.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`filter`** on `array` to filter all the `Strings` that contain the `searchText`, i.e.

```
let array = ["Anand", "Ani", "Dan", "Eion", "Harsh", "Jocab", "Roshan", "Stewart"]
let searchText = "R"
let filteredArray = array.filter({$0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})
let sortedArray = filteredArray.sorted { (str1, str2) -> Bool in
    if let index1 = str1.lowercased().firstIndex(of: Character(searchText.lowercased())), let index2 = str2.lowercased().firstIndex(of: Character(searchText.lowercased())) {
        return index1 < index2
    }
    return false
}
print(sortedArray) //["Roshan", "Harsh", "Stewart"]
```

Comment: I am looking results in  ["Roshan", "Harsh", "Stewart"] order

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: The solution work if search text is char but if text with more than 1 char it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
let words = ["Anand", "Ani", "Dan", "Eion", "Harsh", "Jocab", "Roshan", "Stewart"]
let keyword = "r"
let result = words.filter { $0.contains(keyword) }
    .sorted { ($0.hasPrefix(keyword) ? 0 : 1) < ($1.hasPrefix(keyword) ? 0 : 1) }
```