# (Swift) How to find all strings that matches regex in string

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

```
 func findSrcs(_ content: String) {
            if let match = content.range(of: """
(?<=src=")[^"]+
""", options: .regularExpression) {
                print(content.substring(with: match))
        }
    }
```

Function above needs to return all `src`s in html string. 'Content' is HTML string. 
Function works but prints only the first image's src from Content. How to catch all of them?

Comment: You have to use `NSRegularExpression`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to manually find all occurrences in your string using a while condition similar to the one used in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305891/index-of-a-substring-in-a-string-with-swift/32306142) and get the string subsequences instead of its range:

```
func findSrcs(_ content: String) -> [Substring] {
    let pattern = #"(?<=src=")[^"]+"#
    var srcs: [Substring] = []
    var startIndex = content.startIndex
    while let range = content[startIndex...].range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) {
            srcs.append(content[range])
            startIndex = range.upperBound
    }
    return srcs
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let content = """
<span>whatever</span>
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face">
<span>whatever</span>
<img src="stackoverflow.jpg" alt="Stack Overflow">
"""

print(findSrcs(content))
```

---

This will print

> ["smiley.gif", "stackoverflow.jpg"]