# Extract a word from a string using swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, substring

i want to extract a word from a string something like this:

```
"{"photo" : "95.png",
  "other_name" : "othername",
  "name" : "Painting",
  "services" : [],
  "_id" : "id"}"
```

no i want to extract the value of `name:` from here how do i do that,
so it would be like any text the comes after `"name" : "` is the word i am looking for

i tried something like this

```
let index = onlyName.index(onlyName.index(of: "\"name\"") ?? onlyName.startIndex, offsetBy: 10)
        let mySubstring = onlyName[..<index]
```

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305891/index-of-a-substring-in-a-string-with-swift) question but `onlyName.index(of: "\"name\"")` is giving me null

i know i could just convert it to a json that will be easier but needs to be a string

so how can i get the value of the name,it could be using regx

Comment: That looks like json so decode it first into a struct or a dictionary

Comment: You can decode from json to a String.

Comment: yes i know that but its needs to be a string i have a specific kind of requirement it needs to a string and parse the word that way

Comment: it returned nil @JoakimDanielson

Comment: its just a regular string this data was returned from a `SwiftyJson` response and then i did `rawString()` on it i returned the stringified version of the json object

Comment: If you're using swiftyJSON, why not just get value by its key?
Something like: `let json = JSON(responseData)` then `let name = json["name"].stringValue`

Answer (score 0):

```
"{"photo" : "95.png",
  "other_name" : "othername",
  "name" : "Painting",
  "services" : [],
  "_id" : "id"}"
```

The above is not the valid Json string, if it would be the valid Json string like the one below:

```
"{\"photo\" : \"95.png\",
      \"other_name\" : \"othername\",
      \"name\" : \"Painting\",
      \"services\" : [],
      \"_id\" : \"id\"}"
```

And if you can have valid Json string then you can easily get the value of any of the key i.e.

```
func dictionaryFromJsonString(_ json: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = json.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

And you can use it as

```
let jsonString = "{\"photo\" : \"95.png\",
  \"other_name\" : \"othername\",
  \"name\" : \"Painting\",
  \"services\" : [],
  \"_id\" : \"id\"}"


if let dictionary = dictionaryFromJsonString(jsonString) {
    print(dictionary["name"])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As some people above suggested, that string is probably json, and you have reference to it somewhere in code. In that case, you could simply convert it to data, decode it, and access name:

```
struct MyStruct: Codable {
    let name: String
}

let string = "{\"photo\" : \"95.png\", \"other_name\" : \"othername\", \"name\" : \"Painting\", \"services\" : [], \"_id\" : \"id\"}"

if let data = string.data(using: .utf8),
    let parsed = try? JSONDecoder().decode(MyStruct.self, from: data) {
    print(parsed.name)
}
```