# Convert subscript function from Objective C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, substring, subscript

I am trying to convert some Objective C code to Swift and can't manage to do it right with subscripting.
This is the method I am trying to migrate to Swift:

```
- (NSArray *)rangesOfSubstringAlphaNumeric:(NSString *)substring rangesLimit:(NSUInteger)rangesLimit {
    NSAssert(rangesLimit, @"A range limit grather than 0 must be specified");
    if (!substring.length) {
        return nil;
    }
    static NSCharacterSet * restrictedCharacters = nil;
    if (!restrictedCharacters) {
        restrictedCharacters = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    }
    NSArray * substrings = [substring componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:restrictedCharacters];
    NSMutableArray * allRanges = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSString *searchedString = self;
    for (NSString *stringToMatch in substrings) {
        if (![stringToMatch isEqualToString:@""]) {
            NSRange aRange;
            NSUInteger lastLocation = 0;
            NSUInteger foundRanges = 0;
            while (foundRanges++ < rangesLimit &&
                   (aRange = [searchedString localizedStandardRangeOfString:stringToMatch]).location != NSNotFound) {
                searchedString = [searchedString substringFromIndex:aRange.location + aRange.length];
                aRange.location = aRange.location + lastLocation;
                lastLocation = aRange.location + aRange.length;
                [allRanges addObject:[NSValue valueWithRange:aRange]];
            }
        }
    }
    return allRanges.count ? [allRanges copy] : nil;
}
```

I got stuck on the subscripting part since it seems I cannot assign integer values to Indexes and conversion from Index to Int is out of hand for me I'm kind of stuck, this is what I managed to do:

```
func rangesOfAlphanumeric(substring: String, limit: UInt) -> [Range<String.Index>] {
        guard limit > 0, !substring.isEmpty else {
            if limit == 0 {
                assert(false, "limit must be greather than 0")
            }
            return []
        }
        var searchedString = self
        let substrings = substring.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.restricted)
        for stringToMatch in substrings {
            if !stringToMatch.isEmpty {

//                var aRange: Range<String.Index>?
//                var lastLocation: UInt = 0
//                var foundRanges: UInt = 0

//                while foundRanges < limit,
//                    let tempRange = searchedString.localizedStandardRange(of: stringToMatch),
//                    !tempRange.isEmpty {
//
//                        searchedString = String(searchedString[tempRange.upperBound...])
//                        if let lastLocation = lastLocation {
//                            aRange = temp
//                        }
//                }

            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:** Solution below.

Comment: @matt if i wanted to use NSRange I would have used that, what is unclear regarding my question when you just said that I want to convert Objective C to Swift? and use subscripting instead of NSRange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue using the `ranges` function posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32306142/1310984):

```
func rangesOfAlphanumeric(substring: String) -> [Range<String.Index>] {
    var searchedString = self
    let substrings = substring.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.restricted)
    return substrings.compactMap { (stringToMatch) -> [Range<String.Index>]? in
        guard !stringToMatch.isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }
        let ranges = searchedString.ranges(of: stringToMatch, options: [
            .diacriticInsensitive,
            .caseInsensitive
        ])

        if let lastRange = ranges.last {
            searchedString = String(searchedString[index(after: lastRange.upperBound)])
        }
        return ranges
    }.flatMap{$0}
}
```

Comment: So it’s a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/32306142/1310984?

Comment: "Managed to resolve the issue using the ranges function". So no, that was part of the solution.

Answer (score -3):

I created this repo with swift 5 is very easy to use
all is already set up. you have just to change the IAP ids

[The Github repo](https://github.com/Jovisx/IAPSwift/tree/master)

Comment: Please don’t post links to external repos, especially ones that don’t answer the question.

Comment: Is this some weird form of spam?

Comment: @matt not spam afaikt , just an odd off topic answer