# Slicing Strings Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ios13

I want to slice a very long string from one word to another. I want to get the substring between those words.
For that, I use the following string extension:

```
 extension String {
 func slice(from: String, to: String) -> String? {

 guard let rangeFrom = range(of: from)?.upperBound else { return nil }

 guard let rangeTo = self[rangeFrom...].range(of: to)?.lowerBound else { return nil }

 return String(self[rangeFrom..<rangeTo])
 }
```

That works really good, but my raw-string contains a few of the "from" "to"-words and I need every substring that is between of these two words, but with my extension I can ony get the first substring.

Example:

```
let raw = "id:244476end36475677id:383848448end334566777788id:55678900end543"
```

I want to get the following substrings from this raw string example:

```
sub1 = "244476"
sub2 = "383848448"
sub3 = "55678900"
```

If I call:

```
var text = raw.slice(from: "id:" , to: "end")
```

I only get the first occurence (text = "244476")

Thank you for reading. Every answer would be nice.

PS: I get always an error by making code snippets in stackoverflow.

Comment: Code snippets doesn’t work with Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the ranges of your substrings using a while loop to repeat the search from that point to the end of your string and use map to get the substrings from the resulting ranges:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func ranges<S:StringProtocol,T:StringProtocol>(between start: S, and end: T, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> [Range<Index>] {
        var ranges: [Range<Index>] = []
        var startIndex = self.startIndex
        while startIndex < endIndex,
            let lower = self[startIndex...].range(of: start, options: options)?.upperBound,
            let range = self[lower...].range(of: end, options: options) {
            let upper = range.lowerBound
            ranges.append(lower..<upper)
            startIndex = range.upperBound
        }
        return ranges
    }
    func substrings<S:StringProtocol,T:StringProtocol>(between start: S, and end: T, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> [SubSequence] {
        ranges(between: start, and: end, options: options).map{self[$0]}
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let string = """
your text
id:244476end
id:383848448end
id:55678900end
the end
"""
```

---

```
let substrings = string.substrings(between: "id:", and: "end")  // ["244476", "383848448", "55678900"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather thant trying to parse the string from start to end, I would use a combination of existing methods to transform it into the desire result. Here's How I would do this:

```
import Foundation

let raw = "id:244476end36475677id:383848448end334566777788id:55678900end543"

let result = raw
    .components(separatedBy: "id:")
    .filter{ !$0.isEmpty }
    .map { segment -> String in
        let slices = segment.components(separatedBy: "end")
        return slices.first! // Removes the `end` and everything thereafter
    }

print(result) // => ["244476", "383848448", "55678900"]
```

Comment: this would  fail if there is no match found. try string = "abc" it would result in  "["abc"]'

Comment: @LeoDabus Yep, I'm just following the data format OP specified. There's plenty of trivial ways to harden this code against unexpected inputs, but that complicates the example and detracts from the essence of what I'm demonstrating.