# Swift Get String before Substring

Tags: swift, indexing, substring

I have a string, this string changes constantly.

I grab a part of my string which in code can be called `let mySub = "xyz"`

The original string is something that is changing over time, so dont worry how I get `mySub` for this example lets say the string is `let baseString = 123123xyz1234`

How would I be able to grab a substring of everything before `xyz` without it being hard coded so the position of `xyz` can be different and the substring grabbing still works correctly?

Comment: Is performance something that should be considered? Do you only need everything before "x"? What happens if no "x" is found?

Comment: This should give a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32305891/1187415.

Comment: Concretely this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45477831/1187415.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find first matching range of `mySub` in `baseString`, and if found, get previous part.

```
let baseString: String = "123123xyz1234"
let mySub = "xyz"
if let range = baseString.range(of: mySub) {
    let beforeStr = baseString[..<range.lowerBound]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the lowerbound index of the range of your substring and get the substring upTo that index. If you would like to make a caseInsensitive of diacritic insensitive search you can use localizedStandardRange:

```
extension StringProtocol  {
    func substring<S: StringProtocol>(upTo string: S, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> SubSequence? {
        guard let lower = range(of: string, options: options)?.lowerBound
        else { return nil }
        return self[..<lower]
    }
    func localizedStandardSubstring<S: StringProtocol>(upTo string: S, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> SubSequence? {
        guard let lower = localizedStandardRange(of: string)?.lowerBound
        else { return nil }
        return self[..<lower]
    }
}
```

---

```
let string = "123123xyz1234"
if let substring = string.substring(upTo: "xyz") {
    print(substring)  // "123123\n"
}
```

---

```
let localized = "123123café1234"
if let substring = localized.localizedStandardSubstring(upTo: "CAFE") {
    print(substring)  // "123123\n"
}
```