# Replace in string with regex

Tags: swift, regex

I am struggling to modify captured value with regex.

For example, I wanna change `"Hello, he is hero"` to `"HEllo, HE is HEro"` using Regex.

I know there are ways to change this without regex, but it is just an example to show the problem. I actually use the regex instead of just `he`, but I cannot provide it here. That is why using regex is required.

The code below somehow does not work. Are there any ways to make it work?

```swift
"Hello, he is hero".replacingOccurrences(
                of: #"(he)"#,
                with: "$1".uppercased(), // <- uppercased is not applied
                options: .regularExpression
            )
```

Comment: .uppercased will make the literal `"$1"` uppercased, not the captured group.

Comment: how can I apply . uppercased for captured value?

Comment: If I knew I would have told you. Just wanted to let you know why your current solution doesn't work

Comment: I think you need to work with Range here so you can manually uppercase each match, see for instance [this article](https://nshipster.com/swift-regular-expressions/)

Comment: `using regex is required` - why? You need an output, any kind of code that accomplishes this should be ok, why do you specifically need a regex soution?

Comment: it is just an example. I actually using regex instead of just `he`.

Comment: So you need to uppercase the parts of the strings that match a given regex? Is this your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `NSRegularExpression`. Something like:

```
import Foundation

var sourceStr = "Hello, he is hero"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(he)")
let matches = regex.matches(in: sourceStr, range: NSRange(sourceStr.startIndex..., in: sourceStr))
regex.enumerateMatches(in: sourceStr, range: NSRange(sourceStr.startIndex..., in: sourceStr)) { (match, _, _) in
            guard  let match = match else { return }
            guard let range = Range(match.range, in: sourceStr) else { return }
            let sub = sourceStr[range]
            sourceStr = sourceStr.replacingOccurrences(of: sub, with: sub.uppercased(), options: [], range: range)
    }

print(sourceStr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use your regex in combination with Range (`range(of:)`) to find matches and then replace each found range separately

Here is a function as an extension to String that does this by using `range(of:)` starting from the start of the string and then moving the start index to match from forward to after the last match. The actual replacement is done inside a separate function that is passed as an argument

```
extension String {
    func replace(regex: String, with replace: (Substring) -> String) -> String {
        var string = self
        var startIndex = self.startIndex
        let endIndex = self.endIndex

        while let range = string.range(of: regex, options: [.regularExpression] , range: startIndex..<endIndex) {

            if range.isEmpty {
                startIndex = string.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
                if startIndex >= endIndex { break }
                continue
            }
            string.replaceSubrange(range, with: replace(string[range]))

            startIndex = range.upperBound
        }
        return string
    }
}
```

Example where we do an case insensitive search for words starting with "he" and replace each match with the uppercased version

```
let result = "Hello, he is hero. There he is".replace(regex: #"(?i)\bhe"#) {
    $0.uppercased() 
}
```

Output

> HEllo, HE is HEro. There HE is

Comment: Your method will result in an infinite loop if the resulting range of the regex represents an empty string. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32306142/2303865) for a proper implementation which supports substrings as well

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, I didn't think about that edge case

Answer (score -1):

this is the solution i can provide

```
var string = "Hello, he is hero"
let occurrence = "he"

string = string.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(
    of: occurrence,
    with: occurrence.uppercased(),
    options: .regularExpression
)
print(string)
```

Comment: thanks for answering. but if occurrence is like `^he\d+`, it doesn't work.

Comment: You can’t lowercase the whole string, this might change other characters that shouldn’t be replaced.

Comment: oh i seem, in that case we can change the option to `.caseInsensitive` and remove the `.lowercased()` correct?

Comment: Yes but you still need to supply a proper regex, now you only have a plain string. And this is will never work using `replacingOccurrenses` as far as I know