# How can I change overflowed characters color of my UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I would like to have the follow result:

[Dream result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcjJD.png)

I tried to use this code, but no success:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if range.location > 159 {

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: bioTextView.text)

        let range2 = (bioTextView.text as NSString).rangeOfString(bioTextView.text)

        attributedString.addAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.flatRedColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 14)!], range: range2)

        bioTextView.attributedText = attributedString

    }
}
```

I saw in this post: [Finding index of character in Swift String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029163/finding-index-of-character-in-swift-string)

That I should not convert to NSString, because can bug with emoji

PS: Sorry about my English, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use following function to achieve your desired result.
Declare max length of text that you want to show in default color, other than that text will be red.

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

let maxLength = 159

if range.location > maxLength {

    let index = textView.text.startIndex.advancedBy(maxLength)

    let mainString = textView.text.substringToIndex(index)

    let mainAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString (string: mainString, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.darkGrayColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 14)!])

    let redAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: textView.text.substringFromIndex(index), attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 14)!])

    mainAttributedString.appendAttributedString(redAttributedString)

    textView.attributedText = mainAttributedString;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It really works!
I just added into the code the follow code:

`let index = textView.text.startIndex.advancedBy(maxLength).successor()`

It's because was painting a character before.