# Why does Swift String.Index keeps its index value 4 times bigger than real?

Tags: swift, string, swift-playground

I was trying to implement Boyer-Moore algorithm in Swift Playground and I used Swift String.Index a lot and something that started to bother me is why indexes are kept 4 times bigger that what it seems they should be.

For example:

```
let why = "is s on 4th position not 1st".index(of: "s")
```

This code in Swift Playground will generate `_compoundOffset 4` not 1. I'm sure there is a reason for doing this, but I couldn't find explanation anywhere.

It's not a duplicate of any question that explains how to get index of char in Swift, I know that, I used index(of:) function just to illustrate the question. I wanted to know why value of 2nd char is 4 not 1 when using String.Index.

So I guess the way it keeps indexes is private and I don't need to know the inside implementation, it's probably connected with UTF16 and UTF32 coding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding index of character in Swift String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029163/finding-index-of-character-in-swift-string)

Comment: maybe because every character is represented by an [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) character in Swift...?

Comment: String.Index should be treated as an opaque type. Because f the way Unicode works, it doesn't necessarily go up even in 4's.

Comment: What you show is not the real index you compare with. The real index is 1 and is the `encodedOffset` value of `why` and that is the real index you think it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, don’t ever assume `_compoundOffset` to be anything else than an implementation detail. `_compoundOffset` is an internal property of `String.Index` that uses bit masking to store two values in this one number:

- The `encodedOffset`, which is the index's byte offset in terms of UTF-16 code units. This one is public and can be relied on. In your case `encodedOffset` is `1` because that's the offset for that character, as measured in UTF-16 code units. Note that the encoding of the string in memory doesn't matter! `encodedOffset` is always UTF-16.
- The `transcodedOffset`, which stores the index's offset *inside* the current UTF-16 code unit. This is also an internal property that you can't access. The value is usually `0` for most indices, unless you have an index into the string's UTF-8 view that refers to a code unit which doesn't fall on a UTF-16 boundary. In that case, the `transcodedOffset` will store the offset in bytes from the `encodedOffset`.

Now why is `_compoundOffset == 4`? Because it stores the `transcodedOffset` in the two least significant bits and the `encodedOffset` in the 62 most significant bits. So the bit pattern for `encodedOffset == 1, transcodedOffset == 0` is `0b100`, which is `4`.

You can verify all this [in the source code for `String.Index`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringIndex.swift).

Comment: I assume this representation is because of the new "shared index" between the different views in Swift 4?

Comment: @MartinR: Yes, exactly. Proposed in [SE-0180](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0180-string-index-overhaul.md).